# Ruby on Rails - How to Create Foreign Key in Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm pretty new to rails, so there might be a simple answer.  I'm trying to add a "user_category" column to my "users" table that refers to a "user_categories" table.  I tried the following:

```
rails generate migration add_user_category_to_users user_category:integer
```

and then...

```
rails generate scaffold User_Category title:string description:text
```

But on rake db:migrate I get the following error:

```
==  CreateUserCategories: migrating ===========================================
-- create_table(:user_categories)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "user_categories" already exists: CREATE TABLE "user_categories" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "description" text, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm it's not how you are supposed to do ... I guess you want to have 2 models, 1 `User` has_many `Categories` and 1 `Category` belongs_to 1 `User`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Did you at some point already create a migration for user_categories? Double check your db/migrate directory and see if its already there.

Comment: Not quite.  1 User has 1 Category, but I don't want to store the category names in the database.  It's similar to having a "State" table and referencing the id rather than the full state name dozens of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Active Record way claims that intelligence belongs in your models, not in the database. As such, features such as triggers or foreign key constraints, which push some of that intelligence back into the database, are not heavily used.

Validations such as validates :foreign_key, :uniqueness => true are one way in which models can enforce data integrity. The :dependent option on associations allows models to automatically destroy child objects when the parent is destroyed. Like anything which operates at the application level, these cannot guarantee referential integrity and so some people augment them with foreign key constraints in the database.

Although Active Record does not provide any tools for working directly with such features, the execute method can be used to execute arbitrary SQL. You could also use some plugin like foreigner which add foreign key support to Active Record (including support for dumping foreign keys in db/schema.rb).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I mean.  I understand that the logic belongs in the models, but how do I add a field that refers to another table?  It won't even let me add the models so I can link them within the models... am I incorrect?

Comment: when you generate models like this: `rails generate model another_model:references`, it will generate an `another_model_id` field in migration and index for this field which is usually enough. no foreign keys constraints are needed in your database.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for -- do you have a link where I can read more about that?

Comment: follow the link I added in my answer, and this too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, it should be enough to understand the whole thing :)

Comment: In my case would it look like `rails generate model user_category user:user_category`?

Comment: `rails generate model user_category user:belongs_to` or `rails generate model user_category user:references` which are the same.

Comment: Wow, great.  That'll do it.  Thanks!